# Minecraft Render Blank Spaces

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh

I'm using Tomy's Minecraft Render for my minecraft skin render. Why do the arms have holes at the end of them?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try flipping your normals on those faces in edit mode. You may just want to do a select all and a recalculate under the UV tools. Or you could just make your mesh objects Double Sided.

Answer (score 0):

Your skin is a slim-armed skin. Try making a "Steve" modeled skin (one without slim arms) and use that one.  This glitch occurs in minecraft because it tries to apply a slim armed skin to a thick arm. This leaves gaps in the texture.